# Create lower-bound for force-directed plot (e.g. Force-Directed Histogram)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I'd like to create what I think is best described as a either a force-directed histogram (or dot/bubble histogram), or a beeswarm where y-values are constrained along the x-axis.

That is, using the force-directed layout, assign x-positions based on some x-value and y-positions based on counts for that value, **where y values must remain above some lower-boundary.**

I've created a [force-directed beeswarm plot](https://bl.ocks.org/jwilber/e5aed3899b822388b6203d2567afe3c4) that is *almost* what I want. I've just not yet figured out the y-axis constraint.

Thanks for any help/suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply such a constrain you can limit `d.y` value directly — just replace

```
.attr('cy', d => d.y)
```

with, for example,

```
.attr('cy', d => d.y = Math.min(d.y, height / 2))
```

This way nodes are forced to be above `height / 2`. It's important not only to constrain `cy`, but to update `d.y` too so this new position will be taken into account on the next iteration. If you don't like to assign in return statement, it's possible to modify `d.y` separately with `each` operator.

`forceCenter` here can mess things up and I'm not sure it's necessary. I doubt the necessity of `manyBody` force as well — why the circles must attract each other (you use positive strength = attraction)? It's better to attract them by the axis instead (`forceY`).

There is a compromise between accurate `x` position of the circles, the attraction of the x-axis and the speed (in iterations) of convergence. Some tuning of force strengths can be needed. Effects of strength are described in `d3-force` readme: https://github.com/d3/d3-force#x_strength. For most forces it's recommended to use strength in [0, 1] range.

```js
const width = 500
const height = 150
const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)

const colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(['#FCFCFC', '#F7567C', '#FFFAE3', '#99E1D9', '#5D576B'])

const radius = 7
const sampleData = d3.range(150).map(() => ({r: radius,
                                            value: width/2 + d3.randomNormal(0,75)()}))

// set params for force layout
//const manyBody = d3.forceManyBody().strength(2)
//const center = d3.forceCenter().x((width/2)).y((height/2))

// define force
let force = d3.forceSimulation()
  //.force('charge', manyBody)
  //.force('center', center)
  .force('collision', d3.forceCollide(d => d.r).strength(1))
  .velocityDecay(.48)
  .force('x', d3.forceX(d => d.value).strength(3))
  .force('y', d3.forceY(height - radius).strength(0.2))
  .nodes(sampleData)
  .on('tick', changeNetwork)

svg.selectAll('circle')
  .data(sampleData)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .style('fill', (d,i) => colorScale(i))
  .attr('r', d => d.r)
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('stroke-width', .1)

function changeNetwork() {
  d3.selectAll('circle')
    .attr('cx', d => d.x)
    .attr('cy', d => d.y = Math.min(d.y, height - radius - 1))
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei for the thorough explanation!